# How to strip leading whitespace before a Nunjucks variable only if the variable string is empty?

Tags: nunjucks

I'd like to support construction of Nunjucks templates where leading whitespace before variables is only stripped if the variable is empty.

A simple example could begin:

```
    Hello {{ firstname }}, how are you?
```

If firstname is "Dave", this renders to "Hello Dave, how are you?".  But if not set, it renders to "Hello , how are you?" with the extra space.

**How can templates be constructed, in a general way (without fore-knowledge of the surrounding text), such that leading whitespace is only stripped before variables if the variable string is empty?**

Using `{{- firstname }}` would always strip leading whitespace (so doesn't work if the variable is not empty, resulting in "HelloDave" in the example above
).

Something like the following works for this specific case (or better, the approaches suggested by @AikonMogwai in the comments), but is overly complex and relies on knowledge of the surrounding text (e.g., inserts a space if the variable is non-empty):

```
  Hello
   {%- if firstname %}
     {{- " " + firstname -}}
   {% else %}
     {{- "" -}}
   {% endif %},
```

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates the above examples: https://jsfiddle.net/davebeyer/3L5146jg/  (Click "Run" then "Render".)

Ideally, I'd like to create/use a custom tag (like `{{=`) or custom filter (like `condlstrip` for conditional left-strip) so that templates can be constructed using something like:

```
  {{= firstname }}
```

or

```
  {{ firstname | condlstrip }}
```

But it's not clear to me how to create a custom `{{=` tag, and also not clear whether filters, like condlstrip, can affect rendering outside of the tags.

Regarding the requirement  "without fore-knowledge of the surrounding text," this specifically means that the solution should not assume that there will always be a space in front of the variable.   For instance, it should also work in a case like the following (using my wished-for `{{=` tag), and where the user is fairly confident that school and studentId are set, but firstname may or may not be set):

```
Hi {{= firstname }}, your user ID is {{= school }}-{{= studentId }} and you can reach your profile at http://{{= school }}.example.com/profiles/{{= studentId }}
```

to produce:

Hi Dave, your user ID is CentralValley-1234 and you can reach your profile at http://CentralValley.example.com/profiles/1234

I.e., it would be great if our system could use the pattern `{{= variable_name }}` to produce reasonable default behavior for inserted variables in templates created by users (who are actually using a graphical, higher-level UI).

Comment: `Hello{{ (' ' + firstname) if firstname }}, how are you?` or `Hello{{ firstname | addSpace }}, how are you?`?

Comment: Thanks for the response @AikonMogwai!   I should have been more clear on the implications of our requirement: "without fore-knowledge of the surrounding text."   Specifically, I'm looking for a solution that does not assume that a space is required before the variable if the variable is non-empty.  See the additional example I added to to the end of my original question above.

Comment: (... and just to add regarding the motivation for this question, there may often be a default value for the variable which would be used if the variable isn't set for a given user, so the question is to handle the worst-case scenario when both the user setting and default for a variable haven't been set.)

Comment: I think that your issue can be solve only through pull-request for `parser.js`. The custom tags doesn't help to do this. The simplest/dirty way is to use `&nbsp;` instead ' ': `{{- ('&nbsp' + filename ) if filename -}}`.

Comment: OK, I was afraid it might require modifications to the parser.   If that's the case, we may just rely on defaults.   (BTW, even using &nbsp; as you have above wouldn't work as a general variable replacement pattern since it assumes that a space [or nbsp;] is always wanted before non-empty variables, which isn't always the case).

Comment: you can use the "string-if-variable" approach: `{{ " " if user.firstname }}{{ user.firstname }}` or the single statement `{{ (" " if user.firstname else "") + user.firstname }}`

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution:

```
<li>Hello{{ " " if user.firstname }}{{ user.firstname }}, how are you?</li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pn8koeg3/

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, this is a simpler approach for this specific "first name" example, or any case where a space could always be added before non-empty variables, but unfortunately, the desired requirement is that "the solution should not assume that there will always be a space in front of the variable".  E.g., see the last few paragraphs in the original question, and in particular, the example with the studentId.  So, the ideal {{= tag would never add white space, and would only remove any leading white space if the variable is empty.

Comment: @DaveB I think you can handle what is inside the `{{}}` or `{%%}`, not outside (the exception is the `{{- -}}` and `{%- -%}`). 

I think the above answer is more readable and can work also for the  school-studentId case, see this: https://jsfiddle.net/ah9ewm4p/

BTW I discourage you to modify the parser.

Comment: thanks but the problem for me in how you handled the school-studentId case ( "{{ user.school }}" and "{{ user.school }}" ) is that it required a different templating pattern than you used for the firstname case ( "{{ ' ' + user.firstname if user.firstname }}") .   I was hoping for a single pattern that could be programmatically used in all cases to remove leading whitespace if the variable is non-empty;  i.e., the elusive "{{= variable }}" pattern.

Comment: ... And yes, in the absence of a "{{=" approach short of modifying the parser,  we are instead relying on use of defaults for variables like 'firstname" when the variable is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
var env = nunjucks.configure();
env.addFilter('ws', val => !val || val == 0 ? val : ' ' + val);

var html = env.renderString(`
    Hi {{- firstname | ws -}}, your user ID ...
`, { firstname: 'Dave' });
console.log(html);
```

Comment: Thanks, but unless i'm missing something, I think this (like the solution proposed in the comments above) also fails the requirement that "the solution should not assume that there will always be a space in front of the variable" (i.e., even for a non-empty variable).   See the last few paragraphs in the original question, and in particular, the example with the studentId.